# JQuery Knob, Stop knob value from changing while using touch or mouse

Tags: jquery, touch, jquery-knob

I am using Knob for a climate control app. Every 10 seconds my script sends an ajax request to get the setPoint (variable of what the requested room temp should be to reach satisfied) from XML, and then this updates the knob value. I am also using Knob release event to call a function that sets the setPoint.

My issue is that sometimes it wil update the value of the knob in the middle of touching or mousing to change the setPoint.

Is there any way to stop the value change if in the middle of touching or mousing the wheel? Below is how i am retrieving and setting the knob value.

`function getCurrentSetPoint() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ControlHandler.ashx",
        dataType: "xml",
        cache: false,
        success: function (xml) {
            //Get Current Set Point
            $(xml).find('object[id="abcdefg"]').each(function () {
                var sTitle = $(this).find('objName').text();
                var sPublisher = Math.round($(this).find('objPresentValue').text());
                $('.setTemp').val(sPublisher).trigger("change");
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
        }
    });
}`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the knob value to be read only so that it is not affected by the mouse events.

See the documentation here:
https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob